# How to enable comments on a static site?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to enable comments (like in any regular blog) but the site is static. How should I do it?

Is there a service to "host" comments (like imgur for comments for example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Disqus](http://disqus.com/welcome/) is almost exactly what you're looking for. They give you a little snippet and it embeds a commenting system in your page. Used by about half of Tumblr and big sites like Engadget.

Comment: How can disqus be integrated with a static site? Their guides offer integration with blogging platforms, but not a simple "copy javascript snippet" solution (https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1257441-adding-disqus-to-your-site)

Answer (score 7):

[Disqus](http://disqus.com/) is a great option, and depending on the type of site [Facebook Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) can make a lot of sense as well. Both will work on a totally static site.

Comment: Thanks. Both are great suggestions. (I accepted Drakekin's because he answered first)

Comment: How can disqus be integrated with a static site? Their guides offer integration with blogging platforms, but not a simple "copy javascript snippet" solution (https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1257441-adding-disqus-to-your-site)

Comment: It looks like they've made it a little harder to find since my original comment a few years ago :)


This looks to be the current snippet you need: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472097-universal-embed-code

Answer (score 4):

To gather all options:

- [Juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia) is an open source alternative to Disqus. The problem is, you would need a server to host it yourself and the development seems to be stuck.
- [Disqus](https://disqus.com/websites/) is very popular.
- [Facebook Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) integrates well with that social network. But it requires people to have a Facebook account.

Comment: How can disqus be integrated with a static site? Their guides offer integration with blogging platforms, but not a simple "copy javascript snippet" solution (https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1257441-adding-disqus-to-your-site)

Comment: @gonvaled You sure?: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472097-universal-embed-code

Comment: indeed, you are right!

Answer (score 3):

Check out Isso, self-hosted and open source.

- Web site: https://posativ.org/isso/
- Github: https://github.com/posativ/isso/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Have a look at this article: [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Even though Disqus is a good answer to the question, I also suggest the service [Muut](https://muut.com/). They give you a snippet to include on every page to embed a commenting system. It seems to be a lighter option though.